# Appcelerator. Creating platform-specific view

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm learning how to create a Titanium app with the help of the lessons. 
Here are the steps given to create the specific view:

To create the iOS-specific view with a NavigationController:

- In Project Explorer, create a new folder named ios in the app/views folder.
- Create a new file named index.xml in the new folder.

But when I do those steps I get a message the a view with such name already exists not allowing me to save it. But this was somehow achieved by the author of the lesson. I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to do it.
https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Creating_Your_First_Titanium_App

Comment: if you already have a index.xml in your project just edit it, no need to create another.

Comment: but the lesson tells to add it. Was this just possible earlier?

Comment: i dont have much experience currently with titanium but it seems to be a general problem rather then specific to titanium stuff. Also the doc seem to be written around 8 months ago or so from its example proj. Not sure if it is has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Create new file into app/views/ios folder. I followed the steps of the tutorial and it works perfectly.
[image]
[image: Project with custom index for ios]

Comment: Can you build your app after that?

Answer (score 0):

- First create a new project from Studio.
- Studio will automatically create the necessary files with a Label and a click event to it.
- Finally all you need to run your app is to select iOS simulator and hit Run button (in green colour arrow).
- Now if you are a pure beginner to Titanium, then I would advise you to go through with simple steps and one step at a time to learn it more effectively.
- According to @Jagu's answer, he has created a different folder for iOS and there are two index.xml files, it means that if you run your app on iOS then app->views->ios->index.xml file will run, and if you run the app on other platforms then app->views->index.xml file will be run.
- You will gradually learn these platform specific techniques, but first try to get good hands on very basic things and always refer [Titanium Documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Hello_World). Some documentations could be older, so always rely on whatever Titanium Studio setup things initially and try to refer more resources over internet.

Good Luck!!!